# Laravel throws 'Conncetion refused' error occasionally

Tags: php, laravel

I have a payment form in a laravel project with working database credentials.

> Laravel version : 5.1.36, 
>   PHP version: 5.5.9

But on submit it occassionally returns the following error and occassionally it works. I can't figure out why or when it returns this. All the code upon submit runs but the page reloads with this error.

```
[2020-02-06 12:24:04] stage.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused' in /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:55
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(55): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'password', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(22): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=loca...', Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11445): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11441): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11356): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->make(Array, 'mysql')
#5 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11311): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->makeConnection('mysql')
#6 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Connectors/DatabaseConnector.php(38): Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager->connection(NULL)
#7 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueManager.php(133): Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\DatabaseConnector->connect(Array)
#8 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueManager.php(113): Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager->resolve('database')
#9 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(149): Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager->connection(NULL)
#10 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(109): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->pop(NULL, 'index_user,upda...', 0, '3', '3')
#11 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(71): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker(NULL, 'index_user,upda...', 0, 128, false)
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire()
#13 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(1187): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(150): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#15 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(256): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(136): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(841): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(189): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(120): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /var/www/html/testhyl.ajency.in/public_html/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

And I found this in mysql error log

```
2020-02-06T12:24:12.836270Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2020-02-06T12:24:12.839288Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.28) starting as process 3013 ...
2020-02-06T12:24:12.844361Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-02-06T12:24:12.844425Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-02-06T12:24:12.844433Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-02-06T12:24:12.844440Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-02-06T12:24:12.844445Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-02-06T12:24:12.844450Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-02-06T12:24:12.844910Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-02-06T12:24:12.845100Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-02-06T12:24:12.847590Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-02-06T12:24:12.847671Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2020-02-06T12:24:12.847689Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2020-02-06T12:24:12.847698Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2020-02-06T12:24:12.847706Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-02-06T12:24:12.847720Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-02-06T12:24:12.847728Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2020-02-06T12:24:12.847731Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: This might have something to do with the connection pool. Do you have many user at once ?

Comment: No. It's a staging site. I'm the only one testing it

Comment: Do you have enought RAM on your environnement ? Sometime the server will priorise Apache / PHP over Mysql. Try looking at your mysql logs.

Comment: I have added the mysql log. Can you check?

Comment: That's what i thought: `cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool`. Your mysql need more RAM.

Comment: I never encountered this error before. Is it because the PHP processing of the payment form is too heavy?

Comment: There is a few reason this could happen. Assuming you are on linux, try running the command `htop`, or `top` if `htop` does not exists, to check what is taking all that memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207350/discussion-between-saeesh-tendulkar-and-nicolas).

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.